# Exception after code conversion from Java to Kotlin: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.misc.Restaurant

Tags: android, kotlin

I am in a process of converting my app from Java to Kotlin and I am getting a ClassCastException  while executing the code below. Thoughts?

```
private fun getImageFragments(imagesList: MutableList<Restaurant?>?) {

   if (imagesList != null) {

   val restaurant: Restaurant? = imagesList[0] 
/*exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
  java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.misc.Restaurant */    

   }
}
```

Not sure if the implementation of the Restaurant Class is of any importance in this case? https://pastebin.com/q5z76exh

While inspecting the contents of imagesList[0] with debugger I am seeing this:

ArrayList size = 1

```
    https://domainName.com/files/app/banners/1550449003515.png
    count=116
    hash:0
    shadow$_klass_=class java.lang.String
    shadow$_monitor_
```

Moreover, when I try to rewrite the problematic line to

```
val restaurant: String? = imagesList[0]
```

I am getting:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Restaurant? but String? was expected
```

EDIT:

So as per requests I am posting some more code, be warned though, it's not going to be pretty. Trust me, I would gladly show you the whole thing if it wasn't closed but the main reason is I don't want you to suffer. Ask if you want more. Here is the code of the function that is calling getImageFragments:

```
getDrawerBanners(App.preference.getString("language", "ENG"),
object : OnAPIRequestListResultListener<Restaurant?> {

    override fun onListResult(list: MutableList<Restaurant?>?) {
        bannerViewPager.adapter = fragmentManager?.
        let{ DrawerBannersAdapter(it, getImageFragments(list)) }
    }
})
```

And here is OnAPIRequestListResultListener interface, I have a strong feeling that error might be hidden smowewhere here, if you think otherwise read on further.

```
interface OnAPIRequestListResultListener<T> {
                fun onListResult(list: MutableList<T>?)
            }
```

Original signature + body of getDrawerBanners function

```
 // Downloading banners  from server
    @JvmStatic
fun getDrawerBanners(languageCode: String?, listener:
OnAPIRequestListResultListener<Restaurant?>) {
    val async = GetMenuBannersAsync(listener)
    async.execute(languageCode)
}
```

GetMenuBannersAsync

```
private class GetMenuBannersAsync(var listener: 
OnAPIRequestListResultListener<Restaurant?>) : AsyncTask<String?, Void?, Void?>() {
        var bannersUrls: MutableList<Restaurant?> = ArrayList()

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): Void? {
            val url = "https://api.smartapp.com/App/Language/" + params[0]
            val client: HttpClient = DefaultHttpClient()
            val httpGet = HttpGet(url)
                httpGet.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, AUTHORIZATION_STRING)
            var httpResponse: HttpResponse? = null
            var httpEntity: HttpEntity? = null
                httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet)
                httpEntity = httpResponse.entity
            val response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)
            val json = JSONObject(response)
                // Getting drawer banner
            val bannersArray = json.getJSONArray("mainMenuBanners")
                bannersUrls = ArrayList()

            for (i in 0 until bannersArray.length()) {
                val bannerObj = bannersArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val imageUrl = bannerObj.getString("image")
                    (bannersUrls as ArrayList<String>).add(imageUrl)
            }

            return null
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
            listener.onListResult(bannersUrls)
            super.onPostExecute(result)
        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems like your list contains a String object instead of a Restaurant. This can happen if you use reflection or for example your serialization library that uses reflection under the hood. Have you checked the actual content of the list with a debugger?

Comment: Show the code where You prepare paremeter imageList before call function getImageFragments.

Comment: @Jannik Hello, yes, I did check the content in debugger, it does contain the URL link I want to display in the end.  I've updated the question with appended contents of the list shown in debugger.

Comment: Seems a weird problem, probably there's some function with `@UnsafeVariance` annotation in its arguments in the MutableList which may have added String to the list. Can you show how did you created that list?

Comment: Surely this is a bug, I have reproduced it https://pl.kotl.in/Gi028_MdC this might be due to the type-erasure, I'm going to file an issue about this.

Comment: Follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39279 for any updates on this. And post the code where you have created MutableList so that we can help you further.

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejczyk @ Animesh Sahu Thank you so much for your engagement, I've posted some more code.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu That's actually not a problem of Kotlin. When you use a cast you explicitly tell the compiler that it should perform this conversion, without considering the type safety. If you create a list of type `A`, cast it to type `B` and add an element of type `B` you cannot expect that the object you retrieve from the list is of type `A` (assuming `A` is not a superclass of `B`).

Comment: @Jannik it is indeed a bug, you can see in Java you cannot cast an `List<Integer>` to `List<Object>` because they are invariant https://imgur.com/a/PV0KWKQ You can read more about covariance, invariance and contravariance [here](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47). The [KDoc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) of kotlin already suggests that MutableList is invariant by default that means there is no relation between `MutableList<Int>` `MutableList<Any>`, that's why the cast shouldn't be successful.

Comment: @AmonChepri problem is indeed in that line `(bannersUrls as ArrayList<String>).add(imageUrl)`, you should take care of the list and never put anything else than `Restaurant?` but as I said that code should never be compiled hence it is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `GetMenuBannersAsync` function. There you create the `bannersUrls` list with type `MutableList<Restaurant?>` but the you put values into the list with `(bannersUrls as ArrayList<String>).add(imageUrl)`. The cast expression tells the compiler that the conversion you do is save, which it is not in your case.

So always remember that you are on your own if your use a cast and the type system will no longer help you to detect problems. You need to make sure that the conversion is safe do do.

To solve the actual problem you need to create the Restaurant objects and put them into the list instead of urls.

Comment: Problem is indeed in that line `bannersUrls as ArrayList<String>`, but it should never be successful because MutableLists and ArrayList both are invariant.

Comment: I don't see why the code should not compile. The variance does not matter for a cast. If the types are reference types you can cast them as you please. The compiler might warn you about an unchecked cast but that is the programmers problem not the compilers.

Comment: Because they are incompatible types, this is why variances are made, aren't they? Java is already concerned about this and does not allow this afterall.

Comment: Ok, now I see where you where going. The part about the ClassCastException threw me off a bit :). But have a look at the slightly modified code: https://pl.kotl.in/aORaW-CWd The CCE was thrown only because the type of the destination of the value was Int and not Any. You probably meant that the cast in line 3 should fail at compile time as in the java version the second line. Thats a fair point for sure. But at least kotlinc tells you about the unchecked cast that is taking place. Also, in java you can provoke this behavior such that the compiler allows it (see the other lines).

Comment: true, fair point JVM type erasures are so bad, jetbrains issue tracker got a comment with same thing(due to erased generics). :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been fighting this issue for weeks...